# Master theorem - Best case big Oh?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, master-theorem

I am extremely new to Algorithms and time complexity and am going through a book. From what I know of Big-Oh function, it is not unique for any f(n),depending on constants *c* and *n<sub>0</sub>*. My first doubt is whether Master theorem gives the best case Big Oh function or not. My second doubt-might be silly- I got confused after after solving probs 1 and 2 while trying to proceed backwards and validate the answers.

[image: Screenshot of problems.]

Now my attempt is as follows- 

1)*cn<sup>2</sup>≥3T(n/2) + n<sup>2</sup>
⇒kn<sup>2</sup>≥T(n/2)

⇒k<sup>''</sup>(n/2)<sup>2</sup>≥T(n/2)* 
 so it is consistent with *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.
Why does the same not go for prob 2,i.e why is it not *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* but *O(n<sup>2</sup>logn)*? I guess there is some maths behind it, and I want to know it (if I have sufficient background until now) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your conditions, Masters theorem gives either the worst-case time complexity `Big-O` or a tight bound `Big-Theta`

Now the actual proof of Master's theorem involves drawing the recurrence tree and some approximations using the geometric series progression. Here's [a link](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2012sp/lectures/lec20-master/mm-proof.pdf) to a pdf containing the process.

Comment: Thanks.But I am still unclear on one thing, whether there is a better theta(asymptote) of worst case for the given *f(n)* or the result of Master theorem is the closest,most accurate one.

Comment: That is, does there exist *h(n)* such that *f(n)=theta(h(n))* and *h(n)=theta(g(n))*

Comment: @DonGod According to the proof, the tight-bound complexity is the closest asymptotically. So as far as we know, there is more accurate tight bound.